# Deploy Provider Hosted App out of Azure

Tags: sharepoint-addin, deployment, provider-hosted-app, azure

I need to change hosting of provider hosted app from azure to my own server, Any body have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To Migerate your web project to your own server you can not no longer use azure ACS certificates you have to create High trust app.
You can follow this msdn link to create High Trust app.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx